# Simulating accelerometers, microphone and camera in XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, camera, accelerometer, microphone

Is it possible to simulate movement (ie the accelerometers), microphone and camera in the XCode simulator?

If so, how do you do it?

If not, are there any XCode addins or third party apps that do it?  (apart from downloading to an actual iPhone of course).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way I found to do it is using the [Wavefront Accelerometer Data App](http://www.wavefrontlabs.com/Wavefront_Labs/Accelerometer_Data.html) that can be found in the App Store.  All you need to do is add a single file to your application then you can use the accelerometer in your iPhone or iPod touch to send data to your app in the simulator.  You'll need a WiFi connection, and a device to use.

You could probably find a solution that runs on the desktop, but you won't be getting accurate real life readings.

I would recommend getting an actual device or your app can behave different than you expect it to.  If this is a serious endeavor, you should be able to justify the cost of a device.  An iPod Touch is much cheaper but you don't get the phone or camera capability.  You can get a headset that has a microphone though.

Those are the limitations, I don't think it wise to develop an app without testing it on a device.  I've run into apps that crash all the time and figure it's because they are getting away with stuff in the simulator that you can't do in the memory and cpu constraints of the device.

Comment: Seems that application is not available in the german iTunes store - or maybe it got pulled entirely?

Comment: It may just be in the US. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Microphone works in the simulator. It uses a standard mic input from your mac.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link....

http://media.wiley.com/product_data/excerpt/72/04705009/0470500972-1.pdf

and go to 10 th page..

However, the iPhone Simulator, being a software simulator for the real device, does have its 
limitations. Features not available on the iPhone Simulator include: 
  Obtaining location data  —  it returns only a ﬁ xed coordinate, such as Latitude 37.3317 
North and Longitude 122.0307 West

Making phone calls
  Accessing the Accelerometer

Sending and receiving SMS messages

Installing applications from the App Store
  Camera
  Microphone

Several features of OpenGL ES

Comment: but suddenly not anymore ... http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/25-Using_iOS_Simulator/ios_simulator_application.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH9-SW1

Answer (score 0):

In the android simulator the hardware can't be simulated .. but for example for the camera i see an approach to get real information ... Use your webcam .. to do that you can get frames with an app and send this data with a socket to the simulator... maybe it's possible to do that with iPhone simulator.

I see this solution [here](http://www.tomgibara.com/android/camera-source)